# Joomla - PHP error message

Tags: php, joomla, require-once

**Latest**: I've managed to download all files properly this time, but I get this message when I'm trying to import my sql file:

The new host has a max limit of 51,200 KiB, my sql file is only 12.5MB and 3.0 MB when zipped. If I upload it as a zip file, it says

```
Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume.
```

Or it displays:

```
#1044 - Access denied for user 'a9806073_blurb'@'localhost' to database '1487929_blurb'
```

However, if I upload it purely as a sql file, the connection resets while it uploads.

---

I just migrated my Joomla files over to a new web host, and I get the following error message:

```
Warning: require_once(/home/a9806073/public_html/includes/defines.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/a9806073/public_html/index.php on line 21

Free Web Hosting

PHP Error Message

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/home/a9806073/public_html/includes/defines.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/a9806073/public_html/index.php on line 21
```

And here's a snippet of the code from index.php:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );

define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
```

Edit: Redownloading the files from FTP, apparently some folders aren't in the same order and appear in the wrong places.

- Original Folder Structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yluCB.png
- Current:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJNNV.png

Comment: It looks like you are missing most of the files.

Comment: Yes, I redownloaded the folders one by one this time, but I get this error when importing my sql file: 'Script timeout passed, if you want to finish import, please resubmit same file and import will resume.'

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can understand PHP, if not the error means that it cannot locate the file 'include/defines.php' from your website.

**Checking**

Have you got these files?

- includes/defines.php

**Side note**

We require more information, I shall edit my answer after getting these information from you:

- Version
- PHP version (phpinfo())

Comment: - Yes, I have defines.php file in the include folder.

- PHP Version: 5.2.* (The one I'm migrating to)

- 5.3.22 (The previous host, but it gives me the option to switch to  5.2.17)

Comment: Attempt a switch to 5.2.17, see if any effect. Whats the joomla version?

Comment: 1.5. Did you see this yet? Amended at the bottom. Original Folder Structure: http://i.imgur.com/d3IXArG.png
Current: http://i.imgur.com/57jPU3Q.png

Comment: It would help if they were both the same style, but different files so I could compare with ease.

Comment: Check the paths in configuration.php

Comment: as well as changing host, I suggest you also update your Joomla version. 1.5 as you should know, is old, insecure and unsupported.

Comment: Make sure you have the right permissions /ownership on the files; and break the sql import in two parts. And by all means upgrade to latest Joomla!